# Hand model keeps bending finger when wrist is rotated

Tags: rigging, bones, blend-modes

I made a rigged hand model from a tutorial that I found on youtube. I have a problem where if I rotate the wrist part of the bone the pinky also rotates. How can I fix this problem?

Here are some pics below of the issue.

[image]

file here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Q_BpDCNgg6b1BFVDFuQXhmODg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the last bones on that finger have a bone constraint with "world space" instead of "local space", as ll the others have

[image]